# What method is used to generate number from RFID /NFC serial number

Tags: algorithm, nfc, serial-number

I have a NFC fob which I am scanning and able to get the serial number by using [NFC tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wakdev.wdnfc&hl=en_AU).

For example when I scan a existing fob, I get the serial number as:
 `5B:29:D8:52:DC:80:07:E0` but the serial that exists in the system (vendor software) , `80E00780DC52D82949`

I tried converting the value to binary, but it does not match.

Just wanted to understand, is there a standard way of generating numbers from serial number or it could differ from vendor to venfor?

After some debugging I am able to establish a pattern that apart from 1st number , all others are reversed in the series. Now , need to understand how 5B is translated to 49 .

Need a pointers on how those numbers are generated (bit-wise-shift, hex values ??)

[image]

Comment: Both look like random numbers in hexadecimal. Are you sure these are the same serial number you're looking for? I think adding more details about specific vendor/model to your question may be useful.

Comment: @yeputons, When I scan with NFC tool , I am getting the serial number with : separators and when looking inside system getting the serial number.We are currently  using this products, http://nebula.wsimg.com/85f1138f936bc4cc02bf115df5f3770a?AccessKeyId=3F2389402813F1618A01&disposition=0&alloworigin=1

Comment: The first number looks like and is formatted as a [MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address).  Not specific to NFC or RFID, every network-enabled device must have a unique one.  Even two fobs from the same manufacturer that are the exact same make and model will have different ones.   The second number smells like the [NFC UID](https://help.gototags.com/article/nfc-uid/).  There is no correspondence between the two, they do different jobs.

Comment: Do you have other pairs? With just a single pair it could be anything...